# jquery in ajax.load loader showing every "mouseover"

Tags: jquery, ajax

i hope subject is clear, i try to explain better my problem.

I have a menu and i'd like to load submenu just on mouseover on parent li of menu.
It works, but every time i go on parent, i see loader.
I'd like that loader to be visible just on first mouseover.
You can see it here:
http://v2.profumee.com

Thanks in advance.

This is the code:

```
function pageLoad() {

            var SessionLingua = '<%= Session("Lingua") %>';

            $(".LinkPadreBoxMenu").mouseover(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault(); //preventing button's default behavior
                    var IDCategoriaGenitore = $(this).next("#LblIDCategoria").html();

                    $('.A_' + IDCategoriaGenitore).show();

                    $(".SottoCategorieAjax_" + IDCategoriaGenitore).load('/' + SessionLingua + '/ajax_categorie.aspx', { 'IDCategoriaGenitore': IDCategoriaGenitore }, function () {
                        $('.A_' + IDCategoriaGenitore).hide();
                    });
                    event.stopPropagation();
                });

        }
```

Comment: Load the whole menu on page load. There is no need to disturb server for each mouseover on parent menu.

Comment: in your code check if $(".SottoCategorieAjax_" + IDCategoriaGenitore).html() is string empty. That means the menu didn't load. Only in that case show animation and call ajax get load content, otherwise just make it visible. For example, "Make up" is 16, so $(".SottoCategorieAjax_16").html() should be empty until you mouse over that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use localStorage to store some value on ajax call. Now next time when you hover, check whether you have localstorage value. By this, you can condition you loading image.

Answer (score 0):

```
function pageLoad() {

            var SessionLingua = '<%= Session("Lingua") %>';
            var vars = {};

            $(".LinkPadreBoxMenu").mouseover(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault(); //preventing button's default behavior
                    var IDCategoriaGenitore = $(this).next("#LblIDCategoria").html();


                    if (vars['Menu' + IDCategoriaGenitore] != true){
                        $('.A_' + IDCategoriaGenitore).show();

                        $(".SottoCategorieAjax_" + IDCategoriaGenitore).load('/' + SessionLingua + '/ajax_categorie.aspx', { 'IDCategoriaGenitore': IDCategoriaGenitore }, function () {
                            $('.A_' + IDCategoriaGenitore).hide();
                            vars['Menu' + IDCategoriaGenitore] = true;
                        });
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }
                });

        }
```